# I deleted my php error log file, no new errors

Tags: php, iis, error-log

I deleted my php error log file in `c:Windows/Temp/` and now IIS 7 does not log any errors.

I deleted it because it was HUGE (10GB) and I expected a new one to be created automatically when IIS logged a new error.

This was not the case.

How can I create a new log file that IIS will update automatically?

Comment: Did you restart your IIS service after removing the file?

Comment: Have you tried creating empty file?